# Confidence interval for the gender effect with management employment area

Tags: self-study, anova, fractional-factorial

Suppose we have the following Factorial Experiment:

> A university wants to assess the starting salaries of their MBA graduates. The study looks at graduates working in four different employment areas: accounting, management, finance, and marketing. In addition to looking at the employment sector, the researchers also look at gender. In this example, the employment sector and gender of the graduates are the independent variables, and the starting salaries are the dependent variables.

Suppose I fit in R the following model:

`model <- lm(salary ~ gender + area + gender:area, data = mba)`

How can I construct a 95% confidence interval for the gender effect with management employment area without adjusting for multiple testing?

I have tried the following:

```
library(emmeans)
model <- lm(salary ~ gender + area + gender:area, data = mba)
model.ems <- emmeans(model, ~ gender | area)) 
model.c <- contrast(model.ems, c1 = c(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), by = NULL)
summary(model.c, infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and what I should place at `c1 = c(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`?

Comment: You are welcome to respond with an answer containing  your own example/dataset.

Comment: Is the question, How do I do this in R ? Or is it more of a question about statistics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd just do `pairs(model.ems)`. It doesn't look like you need to specify any custom contrasts, and by leaving `area` as the "by" variable, you will get a comparison of the two genders in each area. There will be no multiplicity correction, since there are just two genders in your dataset, hence just one comparison.

Comment: That's probably the right approach.  But there might be variations if, for example, there are more than two genders (considering the "*without adjusting for multiple testing*" stipulation).  And there is a question about whether the call should be about *gender | area* or the interaction.  And, finally, if maybe the question is testing the student's ability to specify the contrasts. ...  The question is less specific than it could be...

Comment: Right. I didn't want to get into mind reading, and there is documentation, vignettes, and an index to the vignettes that would be helpful if people bother to read them.